# Java - Natural number counting with various bases

Tags: java

I seen this question posted but got stuck and need a bit help to finish. The program is used to count from one number to another using any base the user inputs.

Example: If the user inputs 5 & 10 with a base of 0123456789 it will output 
5 6 7 8 9 10

From what I have so far I can enter 5 and get the next number 6. But 9 to 10 does no work and only gives me 0. When i enter 19 i get 20. When i enter 99 i only get 00.

So what i need is to fix 9 to 10 and 99 to 100

```
static String nextNum(String base, String n) {
    int i = n.length() - 1;
    char digit = n.charAt(i)
    int pos = base.indexOf(digit);
    if (pos + 1 < base.length()) {
        n = n.substring(0, i) + base.charAt(pos + 1);
    } else if (i > 0) {
        n = nextNum(base, n.substring(0, i)) + base.charAt(0);
    } else if (pos == base.length() - 1) {
        n = n.substring(0, i) + base.charAt(0) + n.substring(i + 1);
    } else {
        n = "" + base.charAt(1) + base.charAt(0);
    }

    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter base: ");
    String base = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter first number: ");
    String n = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter second number: ");
    String m = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(nextNum(base, n));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, but your thinking got fuzzy around the base case.  Assuming that you're working with base 10 and the digits `0123456789`, your algorithm so far does this:

1. (first `if`) If the last digit is not 9, adds one to the last digit
2. (first `else if`) If the last digit is 9 and the length of the string is at least 2, use recursion to add one to the string without the last 9, and append a 0 at the end.

So far, great.  If neither of these two is true, there is only one possibility left (assuming the input is valid): the string is `"9"`.  Given that there's only one possible string at that point, you shouldn't have another `else if`; the problem should be much simpler than you made it.  I'll let you work out the rest.

Comment: Don't you think there are other issue possible? Like, checking if all digits in `n` are in valid base?

Comment: I did say "assuming the input is valid".  The OP is probably making that assumption; I don't see anywhere where his code tried to throw an exception, print an error message, or otherwise do anything special with characters that aren't part of the base string.

Comment: Okay i got it thank you! But one last question if you don't mind. How would  displaying all the numbers between n & m in a string work?

Comment: @YDG14 keep calling your `nextNum` until the result equals `m` (using the `String` `equals()` method).  That's the simplest, but it will get into an infinite loop if `m` has extra 0's at the front, or if it isn't valid or is less than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I recall having posted a concept of adding 2 numbers represented in strings a little while back. I am adding a simplified version of what I mentioned in that answer. User `ajb`'s remarks are spot on about the approach you were taking. So, I won't repeat the same thing.

```
static String nextNum(String base, String n) {
    // 2 cases
    // one requires carry over
    if(n.charAt( n.length() - 1 ) == base.charAt( base.length()-1 ) ) {

        // note: carry is set to 1
        int last = n.length() - 1, carry = 1;

        int systemBase = base.charAt(base.length() - 1) - '0';
        systemBase++;       // equals 10 for base=0123456789
                            // equals 4 for base=0123

        String newString = "";
        int curIndx = n.length() - 1;
        while(curIndx >= 0) {
            int digit = n.charAt(curIndx) - '0';

            // add carry over value
            digit += carry;

            carry = digit / systemBase;
            digit = digit % systemBase;

            newString = digit + newString;

            curIndx--;
        }
        //if there is something left in carry
        if(carry != 0)
            newString = carry + newString;

        return newString;
    } 
    // no carry over
    else {
        // just need to add one to last character
        // increment last character by 1
        int last = n.charAt(n.length() - 1) - '0';  // actual value of last
        last++;                                     // increment by 1
        return ( n.substring(0, n.length()-1) + last );
    }
}       

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter base: ");
    String base = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter first number: ");
    String n = input.nextLine();         

    System.out.println(nextNum(base,n));        

}
```

If `base = 0123456789`, `num = 99`, then `nextNum = 100`. If `base = 0123456789`, `num = 9`, then `nextNum = 10`.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions regarding this.